# How can i add timer to call a funtion to show gps location in every 1 minute

Tags: java, android

I  am creating application for showing Gps location .I need to show location in every 1min.can i use timer.if so kindly provide me timer code.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use `timer` to get location updates. There already is a way to get updates of user's current location.

You should call the `requestLocationUpdates()` method to get the updates of the `lastKnownLocation`.

The method is like,

```
LocationManager mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, this);
```

This will get Last Known Location updates after 1000 milliseconds and 100 meters.

And to get the latitude longitude,

```
Location location;
if (mLocMgr != null) {
    location = mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        System.out.println(latitude+" "+longitude);
    }
}
```

Refer **Location Manager** in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler();
       Timer    timer = new Timer();
           TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
               @Override
               public void run() {

Comment: handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() { 
                          try {
                           displayCurrentLocation();
                              }
                        catch (Exception e) {

Comment: }
                   });
               }
           };
           timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask ,5*100);

Comment: this is my timer code i need to show location in every 1min

Comment: As I said, you cannot use timer to get location updates. You MUST use Location Manager as I have said in my answer

Comment: how to add .while adding i lost my gps location

Comment: go through any tutorial. Google it

Answer (score 0):

As per your query I understand that you would like to request a location update every 1 minute and you have written a handler for it. Try the following code which worked for me.

```
        LocationManager mlocManager;
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

    //paste this in your handler or timer
    {
    if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                    mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mlocListener, null);
                } else if (mlocManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            mlocListener, null);
                }
    }

    //this the class to get the location.
        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
//you may store these values where ever required. 
                    Double latitude =  location.getLatitude();      
                    Double latitude =  location.getLongitude(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }
```